Computer mouse and mouse in Ukranian
I perform a magic show for children where I pretend to locate a mouse in my suitcase. The prank involves it being a computer mouse. I will be presenting my show to children in Ukraine. I don't speak any Ukranian, except for a few words. Does the word "миша" apply to both the animal and to the computer mouse?

Yes, you can use word миша for both.


Does the word "миша" apply to both the animal and to the computer mouse?

Yes.
You can see in Ukrainian Wikipedia: Article Миша is about genus Mus, and it also has link to Миша (значення), which has link to Комп'ютерна миша.
